# $_GET and $_REQUEST are empty, but only sometimes?

Tags: php, apache, http

I have a very simple page.php that should display all URL parameters. (I am having this issue in a more complex page but stripped it down to only this test, and the issue persists)

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { 
    session_start(); 
}
print_r($_GET);
?>
```

When I navigate directly to page.php?someProperty=testing , I sometimes get an empty array(), followed by working as expected on the second attempt, and every subsequent attempt. It seems to always fail the first time I make a request from the server after having been away for a while. I'm beginning to think it's something lower level. It's very difficult to debug because as soon as I observe it, it goes away. What could cause this?

**Environment Info:**

- PHP 5.3
- Apache 2
- Redhat Linux

PS - I've read other similar posts, but in each case, someone had forgotten to initialize a session or something. I also made sure no whitespace or headers are set before the session is initialized

Update - When the page fails to read the URL parameters, the browser also immediately drops the query string from the location bar as well, reducing it to domain.com/page.php
Even if I manually type in the full address for page.php?test=test into the URL bar, it just immediately shortens, and the page outputs a blank array. Also, there is no rewriting of any kind enabled in Apache

Comment: Where are you getting the $_GET from? I mean, $_GET is quite general, you're not defining what parameter from $_GET you're trying to output. Like, are you trying to get something like "user" from a url like this: http://mywebsite.com/index.php?user=130252

Comment: I don't see how $_GET is relevant to sessions, then again, I don't use sessions. However, I know $_GET is related to contents in the url.

Comment: Is this just a browser caching issue? CTRL+F5 empties the cache. Or most browsers have a mechanism of turning cache off, which is quite a good idea when testing scripts you are developing

Comment: Thanks, everyone. TBH, I'm not totally sure why session would be relevant, but it was a common response in other posts and I wanted to eliminate that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just for testing purposes, please also include something like `print_r($_REQUEST);` and check its output.

Comment: Thanks. I get the same empty array when I test $_REQUEST. Sorry, I wrote that I had tested $_REQUEST in my post's title, but did not illustrate that in the code

Answer (score 0):

Why is session_start inside the if isset of $_SESSION?
You cannot read $_SESSION until the session is started.
Perhaps this is causing your problem.
Your code should start with session_start

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) { 
        // Do something
    }
    print_r($_GET);
?>
```